# Android Annotations EActivity isn't getting one of the Extras

Tags: java, android, android-annotations

I'm using Android Annotations on my `NavControllerActivity` which has two `@Extras`. One extra is a parcelable custom class, `BaseEntity` and the other is a `java.lang.Class` object (which is Serializable). However, when my Activity starts up, I'm only getting the `entity`, I'm not getting the `rootFragmentClass`.

```
@EActivity
public class NavControllerActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Extra
    BaseEntity entity;

    @Extra
    Class rootFragmentClass;

    // ....

    @AfterExtras
    public void setupViews() {

        Log.d("Nav", "rootFragmentClass: "+this.rootFragmentClass);
        Log.d("Nav", "entity: "+this.entity);


    }

}
```

I launch the activity like this:

```
NavControllerActivity_.intent(this)
    .rootFragmentClass(EditAnimalFragment_.class)
    .entity(entity)
    .start();
```

When `setupViews()` is executed, my `entity` has the correct value, but the `rootFragmentClass` is null.

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: I think something is going wrong during extracting the extra. You should put a breakpoint in the generated code where this happens and debug it.

Comment: I've stepped through the writeToParcel() method and the constructor which reads from the parcel and both of those functions completed without any issues. :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made some code changes which fixed the problem and here's my assumption about what was really going wrong.

The error I made was in my Parcel in/out code. I was writing 20 fields to the Parcel, but when reading from the Parcel I was only reading 15 fields. Making sure my in-code matched my out-code made the problem go away.

I wasn't getting any exceptions when I first encountered this, but when I was doing more investigation as to what was going wrong ([Android Annotations, Parcelable object as Extra, producing IllegalArgumentException: is not a constant in android.text.Layout$Alignment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39553248/android-annotations-parcelable-object-as-extra-producing-illegalargumentexcept?noredirect=1#comment66431714_39553248)) I finally did get an exception.

That eventually lead me to realizing that my in-code didn't match my out-code.

I think what was happening is that since there was still data to unparcel that it was screwing up another item that needed to get unpacked and throwing an exception that seemed unrelated.