# Android Annotations, Parcelable object as Extra, producing IllegalArgumentException: is not a constant in android.text.Layout$Alignment

Tags: java, android, android-annotations

I've got a class that is Parcelable and its data members are made up of Strings, Integers, Booleans, Dates, and other Parcelable objects which are made up of the same kinds of things. At the end of the tree though, it's only Strings, Integers, Booleans, and Dates (java.util.Date).

I have an `@EActivity` with an `@Extra` called `entity` that is one of these Parcelable objects.

I have an `@EFragment` with an `@FragmentArg` called `entity` as well. When I launch the Activity, I pass the `entity` along to the Activity and in `onCreate` the activity passes it along to the fragment.

However, I get this WEIRD exception that makes no sense:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.my.app/
com.my.app.NavControllerActivity_}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
  is not a constant in android.text.Layout$Alignment
```

None of my values have anything to do with `android.text.Layout`, they are all just `java.lang.String` objects.

I'll put the entire stack trace below, but the point where it leaves my code is here in the `NavControllerActivity_` code generated by android annotations:

```
private void injectExtras_() {
    Bundle extras_ = getIntent().getExtras();
    if (extras_!= null) {
        if (extras_.containsKey(ENTITY_EXTRA)) { // THIS CALL EVENTUALLY LEADS TO THE EXCEPTION
            this.entity = extras_.getParcelable(ENTITY_EXTRA);
        }
        if (extras_.containsKey(ROOT_FRAGMENT_CLASS_EXTRA)) {
            this.rootFragmentClass = ((Class) extras_.getSerializable(ROOT_FRAGMENT_CLASS_EXTRA));
        }
        if (extras_.containsKey(ROOT_FRAGMENT_NAME_EXTRA)) {
            this.rootFragmentName = extras_.getString(ROOT_FRAGMENT_NAME_EXTRA);
        }
    }
    setupViews();
}
```

Here is how I launch the activity:

```
NavControllerActivity_.intent(this)
    .rootFragmentClass(EditAnimalFragment_.class)
    .entity(entity)
    .start();
```

Here is the full stacktrace:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.my.app, PID: 30978
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.my.app/com.my.app.NavControllerActivity_}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:  is not a constant in android.text.Layout$Alignment
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:  is not a constant in android.text.Layout$Alignment
    at java.lang.Enum.valueOf(Enum.java:200)
    at android.text.Layout$Alignment.valueOf(Layout.java:2017)
    at android.text.style.AlignmentSpan$Standard.<init>(AlignmentSpan.java:33)
    at android.text.TextUtils$1.createFromParcel(TextUtils.java:711)
    at android.text.TextUtils$1.createFromParcel(TextUtils.java:689)
    at android.os.Parcel.readCharSequence(Parcel.java:1659)
    at android.os.Parcel.readValue(Parcel.java:2261)
    at android.os.Parcel.readArrayMapInternal(Parcel.java:2592)
    at android.os.BaseBundle.unparcel(BaseBundle.java:221)
    at android.os.BaseBundle.containsKey(BaseBundle.java:269)
    at com.my.app.NavControllerActivity_.injectExtras_(NavControllerActivity_.java:87)
    at com.my.app.NavControllerActivity_.init_(NavControllerActivity_.java:46)
    at com.my.app.NavControllerActivity_.onCreate(NavControllerActivity_.java:39)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Comment: Are you sure that the entity only contains Strings? From the stracktrace, it seems there is a SpannableString whose deserialization goes wrong.

Comment: I'll check through all of my included Parcelable objects, but if there is a SpannableString in there, it's got to be coming from somewhere other than me. I'm using ormlite to read the values from a db into my object, but it would seem crazy to me that ormlite would be sending back SpannableStrings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you to @WonderCsabo for questioning my assumptions about my parcelling code and the objects being parceled. I made some code changes which fixed the problem and here's my assumption about what was really going wrong.

The error I made was in my Parcel in/out code. I was writing 20 fields to the Parcel, but when reading from the Parcel I was only reading 15 fields. Making sure my in-code matched my out-code made the problem go away.

I think what was happening is that since there was still data to unpack that it was screwing up another item that needed to get unpacked and throwing an exception that seemed unrelated.